# PostgreSQL - column reference 'LibraryID' is ambiguous

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables:

```
A(StudentID, Name, Years)
B(Age, LibraryID)
C(Years, Grade, LibraryID)
```

This is the part of my code giving me troubles:

```
c1 cursor for select LibraryID, Age, Grade, Name from A,B,C where  b.LibraryID = c.LibraryID and c.Years=a.Years;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
column reference "LibraryID" is ambiguous
```

Comment: Try adding a different alias for each LibraryID

Comment: Add alias prefix in select clause too for LibraryID like this: `c1 cursor for select b.LibraryID, Age, Grade, Name from A,B,C where  b.LibraryID = c.LibraryID and c.Years=a.Years;`

Comment: @Harsh I dont get why this is the case. When we sa from A,B,C, doesnt the 3 tables ABC join together at their common attributes? And then from that new table LibraryID, Age and Grade are pulled out?

Comment: @Brandon, nope I don't believe it works that way. You need to clearly specify from which table you are selecting the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed an ambiguous name. You have two `LibraryID` fields in your query: one from table `B` and another from table `C`. You just need to specify the table to pick a field, e.g.:

```
c1 cursor for select B.LibraryID, Age, Grade, Name 
from A,B,C where  B.LibraryID = C.LibraryID and C.Years=A.Years;
```

The fact that you joined these tables on `LibraryID` field in the `from` clause does not make them equal for the `select` clause

Comment: Could you please explain to me how the tables join? It was my understanding that when we state from A,B,C, doesnt the 3 tables ABC join together at their common attributes? And then from that new table LibraryID, Age and Grade are pulled out? So this is why I dont see why we need to state B.LibraryID instead of just LibraryID .

Comment: @Brandon. I mean `join` in terms of SQL language. In a sense, modern SQL engines internally make no difference between "`select` * `from` A `join` B `on` A.f1 = B.f2" and "`select` * `from` A, B `where` A.f1 = B.f2".